# Number theory practice exam questions

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Looking for some help for these two practice problems for my exam. I'll explain to you what I have so far and my ideas.

[image]

So  for this problem, I solved part (a) using induction, it wasnt too tricky. However, now I'm stuck on part B. I've tried many things and have noticed that I have never used the given info about the intersection sets. Any Ideas?

[image]

Here, I am extremely stuck. It intuitively makes sense..I mean I know that the product of two finite sets is a finite set.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What does "$\;i\in [n]\;$" mean?

Comment: Think of it as summation notation. I is an element of [n] and it just keeps looping through elements of [n] which is a set

Comment: Ok, so then what set is $\;[n]\;$ ? The first $\;n\;$ consecutive natural numbers or what? And what does "looping" mean? Do you mean it is a running index of some sort?

Comment: [n] is the first n consecutive natural numbers, as you said. And looping means... yea So for example [3] would i = 1, i = 2, i = 3

Comment: So then, in more common mathematical writing, $$\bigcup_{i\in[n]}A_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\;\;?$$ If so, I wonder why this odd (for me, at least) notation? What book is that?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, but you are correct that they are the same notation. This is in a set/number theory class though so for example if the set was all prime numbers, its just in this case it is contiguous natural ones.

Comment: @k9b http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation should help you get started with MathJax. Images are harder to read (because they don't scale) and impossible to find using search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first: Show that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ if $A\cap B=\varnothing$ (hint: take $f$ bijective $A\to[|A|]$ and $g$ a bijection $B\to[|B|]$, then $x\in A\cup B$ means either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ because the intersection is empty, so you can build a bijection with $[|A|+|B|]$ using $f$ and $g$), this solves the inductive step if you choose $A$ and $B$ properly.

For the second: Again, show $|A\times B|=|A||B|$ (depending on the level of rigor, you might want to prove this by induction on $|B|$, or you can use the previous exercise and express $A\times B$ as a disjoint union of sets), then use it in the inductive step.